# MongoDB throwing error Module not found: 'module'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, webpack

I have a Mongo db setup on localhost:27017 and and trying to connect to it from my app that uses Webpack via Mongoose. I have Mongoose installed as a package. Here is my code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/music-app');

mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("Connected to database")
});
```

I'm pretty sure i've followed the documentation correctly but it's throwing the following compile error:

```
Error in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional/~/resolve-from/index.js
Module not found: 'module' in C:\Users\new\Desktop\Development Projects\music-app\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\require_optional\node_modules\resolve-from
```

There is also another error in the console:

```
webpackHotDevClient.js:216 Error in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js
Module not found: 'dns' in C:\Users\new\Desktop\Development Projects\music-app\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib

 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js 12:10-24
```

Anyone seen this before and know how to resolve it? Is there additional packages I might need to install in node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is because you're trying to use `mongodb` from browser, as `create-react-app` is a front-end app.
You should use a back-end server and use mongodb from there.

You can check out this this full-stack repo having a `nodejs` server with `create-react-app` front-end.
https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo

Answer (score 1):

That is because Webpack can’t statically analyze if (`typeof window === 'undefined'`) in `mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js`

Here is the solution:

```
webpackConfig.plugins = [
...,
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
'typeof window': "\"object\""
}),
...
]

Also, if you get error messages regarding mongoose, check out below configurations.

npm install node-loader --save-dev
npm install require_optional --save-dev
npm install module --save-dev

webpack.config.js

const webpackConfig = {
name : 'client',
target : 'web',
devtool : config.compiler_devtool,
resolve : {
root : paths.client(),
extensions : ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.coffee', '.node']
},
node: {
fs: 'empty',
net: 'empty',
tls: 'empty'
},
module : {}
}

// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// JavaScript / JSON

webpackConfig.module.loaders = [{
test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
exclude : /node_modules\/(?!(lodash-es)\/).*/,
loader : 'babel',
query : config.compiler_babel
}, {
test : /\.json$/,
loader : 'json'
}, {
test: /\.coffee$/,
loader: 'coffee-loader',
exclude: /node_modules|lib/
}, {
test: /\.node$/,
loader: 'node-loader'
}]
```